# Second monitor recognized, but displaying "no signal" - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, monitors

I recently started using Ubuntu 20.04, and in all my installations I always get the same error when displaying my second monitor: "no signal". I can see that my cursor reaches another screen without displaying anything. Here are some observations:[image]

[image]

I hope you can help me!

Comment: My second monitor is connected to the HDMI port, my notebook is in dual boot and is a lenovo s145 with nvidia Mx110.

Comment: Have you installed the nvidia driver? 1- https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers. 2- https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04/